# Is there any way to play the 'Classic' system sounds in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I found a list of sounds [here](https://iphonedev.wiki/index.php/AudioServices) but I cannot seem to find the system sounds under the 'Classic' section in the sound settings page. Is there anyway to access those sounds?

I tried using `/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/alarm.caf` and `/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/sq_alarm.caf` but they sound different from the one I need. Also  tried to look for paths under `/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/` but could not find any.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Julia I am making an app for yachts/boats, and I need that sound for critical alerts in case of emergencies.

Comment: Is using another alarm sound an option?

Comment: We always have an option to use another but that specific tone reflects the urgency of the mater and emphasises it more than other tones. Since it will be used in the sea and in case of an emergency, I want the message to be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `AudioToolbox`, I think you are looking for 1304 or 1005, that is what I get for "Classic > Alarm" on an iPhone.

```
import AudioToolbox

func playAlert(){
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(1304)
}
```

https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/1405202-audioservicesplayalertsound

Comment: None of them sound like the classic alarm tone in iPhone. The one I am looking for sound like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtJzPTsqTMg&ab_channel=soundfxbeats). 

You can find it in iPhone by going to `Settings > Sounds & Haptics > Ringtone > Classic (Under ringtones) > Alarm`

Comment: @MohtasimAbrarSamin Ringtones can't be played programmatically, "sounds" are different from ringtones ringtones are likely under copyright. You likely wouldn't get approved in the AppStore if you used them.